# RUBY split word to letters and numbers

Tags: ruby, split

I would like to ask you for help. I have keywords in this form "AB10" and I need to split i to "AB" and "10". What is the best way?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you consider a regexp? And, how is `AB10CD20` supposed to be split up?

Comment: Please, provide a more general input and more general desired output (also it will be good to describe it with words) to solve the problem. To split `AB10` to `AB` and `10` it may be good just to substring 2 characters: 'AB10'[0,2], 'AB10'[2,2].

Answer (score 4):

One could use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
def divide_str(s)
  s.scan(/\d+|\D+/)
end
```

```
divide_str 'AB10'     #=> ["AB", "10"] 
divide_str 'AB10CD20' #=> ["AB", "10", "CD", "20"] 
divide_str '10AB20CD' #=> ["10", "AB", "20", "CD"]
```

The regular expression `/\d+|\D+/` reads, "match one or more (`+`) digits  (`\d`) or one or more non-digits (`\D`).

---

Here is another way, one that does not employ a regular expression.

```
def divide_str(s)
  digits = '0'..'9'
  s.each_char.slice_when do |x,y|
    digits.cover?(x) ^ digits.cover?(y)
  end.map(&:join)
end
```

```
divide_str 'AB10'     #=> ["AB", "10"] 
divide_str 'AB10CD20' #=> ["AB", "10", "CD", "20"] 
divide_str '10AB20CD' #=> ["10", "AB", "20", "CD"]
```

See [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F), [TrueClass#^](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/TrueClass.html#method-i-5E) and [FalseClass#^](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/FalseClass.html#method-i-5E).

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` like so:

```
my_str.split(/(\d+)/)
```

To split any string on the boundary between digits and letters, use either of these 2 methods:

1. Use [`split`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split) with regex **in capturing parentheses** to include the delimiter, here a stretch of digits, into the resulting array. Remove empty strings (if any) using a combination of [`reject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reject) and [`empty?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/empty%3F):

```
strings = ['AB10', 'AB10CD20', '10AB20CD']

strings.each do |str|
  arr = str.split(/(\d+)/).reject(&:empty?)
  puts "'#{str}' => #{arr}"
end
```

Output:

```
'AB10' => ["AB", "10"]
'AB10CD20' => ["AB", "10", "CD", "20"]
'10AB20CD' => ["10", "AB", "20", "CD"]
```

2. Use [`split`](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split) with non-capturing parentheses: `(?:PATTERN)`, [positive lookahead](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) `(?=PATTERN)` and [positive lookbehind](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors) `(?<=PATTERN)` regexes to match the letter-digit and digit-letter boundaries:

```
strings.each do |str|
  arr = str.split(/ (?: (?<=[A-Za-z]) (?=\d) ) | (?: (?<=\d) (?=[A-Za-z]) ) /x)
  puts "'#{str}' => #{arr}"
end
```

The two methods give the same output for the cases shown.

Comment: I've seen the use of free-spacing regex definition mode (`/x`) for making regular expressions self-documenting, by inserting comments (e.g., `(?=\d)  # positive lookahead asserts next character is a digit`), but not to just insert spaces to make it more readable, which is what you've done. Interesting.